# Replace www in URL with a pattern (wildcard subdomain)

Tags: php

Is there a way to replace

[www.domain.com/new-mexico/albuquerque/businessname-513526.html](http://www.domain.com/new-mexico/albuquerque/businessname-513526.html)

with this:

businessname.domain.com/new-mexico/albuquerque/businessname-513526.html

Which means "www" will be replaced by the name of the business. It should be quite simple but I have no idea how to accomplish this.

Comment: create subdomains?

Comment: No, just moving the businessname and replace the "www." part with the businessname.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you could do with `str_replace`

```
$old_domain = "www.domain.com/new-mexico/albuquerque/businessname-513526.html";
$new_domain = str_replace("www.", "businessname.", $old_domain); //I chose to add the dot along with the www just in case there was another www in the url
```